# How do i add a transparent texture over my material?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to add this rust texture that I found over my brick texture cube. The rust is transparent, and i am selecting a specific area of the cube to have the rust over. I separated the specific faces i wanted the rust on by material, and i added the rust image texture, then plugged it to the roughness node. All that appears is a white square. I tried to texture paint but it doesn't give me the result i want. I followed other tutorials where it said to put both the image textures for (in this case brick and rust) through a mixRGB node, but then the rust appears everywhere on the cube. I tried a different method, this time doing what i mentioned again but in it's own material, (separating the faces, giving it its own material, then adding two images textures, brick and rust, then going through the mixRGB node) which did a bit better, but the brick texture was being stretched whenever i tried to adjust the image in the UV editor. What other solutions are there that i can try out?

(I got the idea of putting the rust on the roughness node from Blender Guru's video on making a subway in 20 mins, but i did not get the same results. The Color Ramp did not change much for me.)

Comment: When mixing through a MixRGB node, plug the alpha output of the transparent texture into the "fac" input of the MixRGB node.

Answer (score 1):

Here - This is a common setup for mixing 2 textures (especially rust, as the noise texture works well to create random "rusty patches, however I used concrete here). You can also use your own texture (if it has a built in alpha, connect as shown). Sometimes as well, texture packs come with alpha "masks" that are their own separate texture. You connect these as a factor the same way. Ultimately, any B&W image can be used as a mix factor. Play around to get what you like. See below:

This is all done on one plane with only one face.

[image: AlphaMix]

Also, it's a bit hard to follow what you were doing with the roughness thing, however, if you have a roughness map, and want to apply it "correctly", mix the maps together with the same mix factor.

Comment: @Chrisopher Bennett That method worked well, I was able to show both textures fine, but it doesn't blend in well with the rest of the face of the cube, since I had selected specific faces. It is not smoothed out around the edges or anything. Plus it tiled everywhere when i selected the entire face. I don't have a map of any sort, it is just a transparent PNG that i was to place under a pipe that is connected to the side of the cube, which in this case a building.

Comment: Hey, glad it worked (sort of). You shouldn't need separate sections for the faces or materials, just use one material for all faces (make sure it's UV unwrapped properly first). When I said "map", I just meant "image". I just used that word because what we are doing is the art of "texture mapping". I hope this is helping, it's hard to tell your actual setup. If you need more, always consider uploading your (minimized if necessary) .blend file. You can do it here -  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i got it to work. The file i had is kinda big, and it was just a small area I was working on, and i thought what i was trying to do would be easy to explain, but i think i got it to work. Thank you.